# Можно ли сгруппировать запрос в блоки по 3 результата?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть N новостей. Хочу применить [Card decks](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-decks) от Bootstrap 4. Для этого хочу сгруппировать результат запроса в блоки по 3 элемента.

Но я не могу понять, как это сделать. Методы типа [group_by](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) или [group](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) дают абсолютно другой результат.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Array/in_groups_of). Он разобьет вашу коллекцию на группы по 3 элемента в каждой. Пример (на [slim](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
- posts.in_groups_of(3).each do |group|
  .card-deck
    - group.each do |post|
      .card
        .card-block
          h4.card-title = post.title
          p.card-text = post.text
```

> А если захотите разбить коллекцию на 3 группы - используйте [in_groups](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Array/in_groups).

Comment: Супер, спасибо. От себя добавлю, что нужно внутри `group.each do |post|` сделать првоерку `if post.present?`, так как пустота будет заполняться `null`.

Comment: @Colibri в таком случае вы можете использовать `.in_groups_of(3, false)` - с параметром `false` в ваших группах не будет nil-элементов.

Comment: Ну тогда вообще безгранично превосходно.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, скорее всего, отлично подойдёт [метод `Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) { |a| p a }
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Коллекции из `ActiveRecord` (и во многих других местах!) содержат этот модуль.

Надо только понимать, что при вызове этого метода будет сделан запрос на всю коллекцию, и разбиваться на "ломтики" (slice) она будет уже в памяти. Но для `in_groups_of` это тоже верно (т. к. он только у массива определён).